# Subset original dataframe based on grouped quantiles

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

This is my `df`:

```
   NAME  DEPTH    A1        A2      A3      AA4     AA5     AI4     AC5     Surface 
0  Ron   2800.04  8440.53   1330.99 466.77  70.19   56.79   175.96  77.83   C
1  Ron   2801.04  6084.15   997.13  383.31  64.68   51.09   154.59  73.88   C 
2  Ron   2802.04  4496.09   819.93  224.12  62.18   47.61   108.25  63.86   C 
3  Ben   2803.04  5766.04   927.69  228.41  65.51   49.94   106.02  62.61   L 
4  Ron   2804.04  6782.89   863.88  223.79  63.68   47.69   101.95  61.83   L 
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

So, my first problem has been answered here:
[Find percentile in pandas dataframe based on groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007073/find-percentile-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-groups)

Using:

```
df.groupby('Surface')['DEPTH'].quantile([.1, .9])
```

I can get the percentiles [.1,.9] from DEPTH grouped by Surface, which is what I need:

```
Surface        
C           0.1    2800.24
            0.9    2801.84
L           0.1    3799.74
            0.9    3960.36
N           0.1    2818.24
            0.9    2972.86
P           0.1    3834.94
            0.9    4001.16
Q           0.1    3970.64
            0.9    3978.62
R           0.1    3946.14
            0.9    4115.96
S           0.1    3902.03
            0.9    4073.26
T           0.1    3858.14
            0.9    4029.96
U           0.1    3583.01
            0.9    3843.76
V           0.1    3286.01
            0.9    3551.06
Y           0.1    2917.00
            0.9    3135.86
X           0.1    3100.01
            0.9    3345.76
Z           0.1    4128.56
            0.9    4132.56
Name: DEPTH, dtype: float64
```

Now, I believe that was already the hardest part. What is left is *subsetting the original df to include only the values in between those `DEPTH` percentiles `.1 & .9`*. So for example: `DEPTH` values in Surface group "Z" have to be greater than 4128.56 and less than 4132.56. 
Note that I need `df` again, not `df.groupby("Surface")`: the final `df` would be exactly the same, but the rows whose depths are outside the borders should be dropped.

This seems so easy ... any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to filter rows within groups it's often simpler and faster to use `groupby` + `transform` to broadcast the result to every row within a group and then filter the original DataFrame. In this case we can check if `'DEPTH'` is between those two quantiles.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({'DEPTH': np.random.normal(0,1,100), 
                   'Surface': np.random.choice(list('abcde'), 100)})
```

#### Code

```
gp = df.groupby('Surface')['DEPTH']

df1 = df[df['DEPTH'].between(gp.transform('quantile', 0.1),
                             gp.transform('quantile', 0.9))]
```

---

For clarity, here you can see that `transform` will broadcast the scalar result to every row that belongs to the group, in this case defined by `'Surface'`

```
pd.concat([df['Surface'], gp.transform('quantile', 0.1).rename('q = 0.1')], axis=1)

#   Surface   q = 0.1
#0        a -1.164557
#1        e -0.967809
#2        a -1.164557
#3        c -1.426986
#4        b -1.544816
#..     ...       ...
#95       a -1.164557
#96       e -0.967809
#97       b -1.544816
#98       b -1.544816
#99       b -1.544816
# 
#[100 rows x 2 columns]
```